# Apache HTTP Server: Timeout 10 Minutes (600s) in httpd.conf; but API timeout after 5 minutes everytime

Tags: httpd, httpd.conf

I have Apache HTTP Server -> Wildfly combination and keycloak as authentication.

```
[root@alt-esb-app01 conf.d]$ httpd -version
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Nov 14 2016 18:04:44
```

I have rest API deployed in Wildfly. I sleep thread for 7 minutes. API logs working till 7 minutes. But Postman or Java client says:

Postman Response:

```
Could not get response
Error: read ECONNRESET
GET https://masterdata.test.chintugrator.cosng.net/AccountsService/api/test
Error: read ECONNRESET
Request Headers
Authorization: Basic dXNlcjE6dXNlcjE=
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: bb514333-62ef-4bac-81ca-2d7ac16b7f07
Host: masterdata.chintugrator.cosng.net
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
```

Apache HTTP Conf:

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

LoadModule auth_openidc_module modules/mod_auth_openidc.so
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf


User apache
Group apache


ServerAdmin root@localhost

ServerName esb-app01.unix.cosng.net:80

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>


DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
TimeOut 600
```

There is included masterdata.conf

```
<VirtualHost 10.0.1.1:1001>
    ServerName masterdata.test.chintugrator.cosng.net

    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass / balancer://masterdata/
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://masterdata

    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Ssl on
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"

    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/net.cosng.chintugrator.test.masterdata_access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/net.cosng.chintugrator.test.masterdata_error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

What other places I can look for Timeout in HTTPD? I added timeout in VirtualHost but same results on postman.

Can it be firewall or network settings?

wildfly:

[image]

Comment: Browsers timeout at 5 minutes. Its possible that your client is the same - it would be trivial to check with packet sniffing.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but had similar problem and solved it today.

In my case, my Apache was using fastcgi, and the conf file i had to change was fastcgi.conf : RequestTimeout="600" (for 10 minutes).

Comment: We dont see any fastcgi conf file